# Symfony2 - resize image after upload

Tags: symfony

I want to generate thumbnails after I upload the file. For image manipulations, I use Avalanche123's ImagineBundle.

I tried using the code in Entity:

```
        $avalancheService = $this->get('imagine.cache.path.resolver');
        $avalancheService->getBrowserPath($this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$path.'/'.$extn[0].'.jpg', 'avatar');
```

But it doesn't help. What can I do?

Comment: It doesn't work. Generating thumbs isn't happening.

Comment: And what if you use `$avalancheService->getBrowserPath($this->getWebPath().'/'.$path.'/'.$extn[0].‌​'.jpg', 'avatar');`?

Answer (score 1):

On this line you try to get a service: `$this->get('imagine.cache.path.resolver')`.

But a code example you're following is supposed to be executed in a controller. There is no `get()` method in an Entity, controller inherits it from `Controller` class that all controllers should extend. So calling `$this->get()` in an Entity is pointless.

This is by design. Entities in Symfony are supposed to be dumb and only represent data they have.

The right thing to do is to either do resize in your controller, or create a service, inject `imagine.cache.path.resolver` into it and call it from your controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Check the variables using dump(var) in twig.  Perhaps $extn[0] doesn't have the correct file or isn't set.  Try poutputting the full getBrowserPath string to make sure it's accurate.